# Search for a pattern and print everything in between that in ruby

Tags: ruby, scripting, pattern-matching

I have a file, I want to go over that file and any time it matches this "LINE_MATCH_START" and this is the only text in that line (except comments or preceding whitespace), I want it to print everything following it till it matches "LINE_MATCH_END" (which also has to be the only text in that line, comments are allowed but this has to be first thing in the line except whitespace). I want it to go over the entire file and save it as many times it catches it.

Example,

```
printf ("this is some text")

// comment LINE_MATCH_START this should be ignored

some_other_code

  LINE_MATCH_START // can have spaces before it and comments after it
oh
this 
should be 
saved
    LINE_MATCH_END
some_other_piece_of_code
LINE_MATCH_START
AGAIN
lets save this part as well
LINE_MATCH_END
```

From the above snippet, there can be space before the "LINE_MATCH_START" and it can have comments on the same line but no other piece of code.

I want my code to save all this part

```
oh
this 
should be 
saved
AGAIN
lets save this part as well
```

How can I do this in ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it gets your output and maybe helps with an idea, but I would work on something more robust.

```
f = File.new('output.txt', 'w')
visible = false
IO.foreach('file_name') do |line|
  case line
  when /\s*LINE_MATCH_START.*/ then visible = true
    next
  when /\s*LINE_MATCH_END.*/ then visible = false
  end
  f.write(line) if visible
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't save my output in a separate file, how can I make it save the line to a new file?